# sqlite3 - table has no column named

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am attempting to create a file to handle sqlite3 databases for me (mostly for practice).

I have tried to add an _id column (integer and primary key), and it doesn't seem to be creating correctly.

The driver code is as below

```
class DB(My_SQL):

  column_headings = ["FName", "SName"]

  def __init__(self):

    self.create_table()

db = DB()

db.add_record("User", "1")
db.add_record("User", "2")
```

The code in the My_SQL class is as below:

```
import sqlite3

class My_SQL:
  
  def create_table(self):
    self.records = 0
    self.db_name = My_SQL.__subclasses__()[0].__name__
    columns = ["_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY"]
    for column in self.column_headings:
      type_column = {int: 'integer', str: 'text', bool: 'BIT'}[type(column)]
      columns.append(f"{column} {type_column}")
    self.sql_create(columns)

  def sql_create(self, columns):
    
    self.conn = sqlite3.connect(f"{self.db_name}.db")
    self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    table = f'''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {self.db_name} ({", ".join(columns)});'''

    self.cursor.execute(table)
  
  def add_record(self, *args):

    self.records += 1

    args = self.format_args(args)
    
    self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {self.db_name} ({', '.join(self.column_headings)}) VALUES ({', '.join(args)})")
  
  def format_args(self, args):

    args = list(args)

    for index, arg in enumerate(args):

      if type(arg) == str:
        args[index] = f"\"{arg}\""
    
    args.insert(0, str(self.records))

    return args
  
  def show_table(self):

    self.cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM {self.db_name}")
    rows = self.cursor.fetchall()

    for row in rows:
      print(row)
```

When it is run, it throws the following error:

```
>>> Line 29, in add_record
>>> sqlite3.OperationError: 3 values for 2 columns
```

When I replace `self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {self.db_name} ({', '.join(self.column_headings)}) VALUES ({', '.join(args)})")` in `add_record` with `self.cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO {self.db_name} (_id, FName, SName) VALUES ({', '.join(args)})")`, it throws the following error:

```
>>> Line 29, in add_record
>>> sqlite3.OperationError: table DB has no column named _id
```

I'm not particularly adept with SQL, so after looking this up, I have no idea what's wrong or how to fix it. I have tried running a select statement to check if it exists, and it doesn't appear to throw an error. Any help?

Comment: It works for me if I insert '_id' into `self.column_headings` just before the call to `sql_create`.

Comment: @snakecharmerb I just tried this and it didn't change anything. I may be adjusting my code incorrectly? Could you post the code that made it work for you?

Comment: Did you originally create the table without an `_id` column, and then add it later?  If that's the case you'll need to drop the table and recreate it (`self.cursor.execute("""DROP TABLE DB""")`, then create the table).  Or you might be able to add the column with `ALTER TABLE`, I don't recall if sqlite supports that use case.

Comment: I created the table with `CREATE TABLE` with _id in to start. That's what doesn't appear to be working. That was in the method 'sql_create`

Comment: @snakecharmerb I ran `self.cursor.execute("PRAGMA table_info('DB');")` and it outputted only the FName and SName columns, so clearly _id is not present

Comment: All I did was insert `self.column_headings.insert(0, '_id')` directly before `self.sql_create(columns)`.  From your last comment, it really seems like you need to drop and recreate the table (or switch to a new database if you want to preserve the current table).